# Can't stream tplink vigi camera using python

Tags: python, opencv, stream, ip-camera, onvif

Hi and good day to everyone.
I have been stuck on this problem for few days already and I really wish someone can help me in this.

I have an VIGI  tp-link camera that I would like to stream from it using python. I know the IP of the camera, username password and port. Basically all the info I might need.
I tried using opecv but I could not stream.
I used the following code

```
import cv2, time
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin123@192.168.1.6:554")
cap.read()
```

but it is not working I tried to change to HTTP with port 80 which is the correct port but still no output. (Note this code worked for different types of IP cameras) I tried so many things really. I tried to use onvif python package https://github.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep and I could connect and use it to add change some configurations (I used port 80) , but I don't know how might this help to stream.

I could stream from VIGI software and I got all the information from there.
If I directly put the ip in the browser this message will show

```
No such file or directory
```

i got these ports from the VIGI software but none of them worked for me
[image]

I really wish someone can help me coz I run out of ideas already

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Python user but I think what needs to be added in your RTSP path is `/stream1` or `/stream2`.

I just got our C300HP-6 to do some testing. I tried to access it through RTSP via VLC but I couldn't seem to make it work. That was until I came upon [their online manual](https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/vigi-security-manager/chapter-7-configure-your-cameras-and-nvrs.html#ug-sub-title-6).

> With Port Forwarding enabled, you can remotely watch the videos with the URL rtsp://A.B.C.D:Port**/streamN**, for example, **rtsp://10.0.1.47:28736/stream1**. A.B.C.D is the WAN IP address of the gateway, and Port is the number of RTSP external port. N can be number 1 or 2 that indicates the stream, 1 for main stream and 2 for substream.